# Get Media player to get MP3 path adress from MySQL

Tags: php

My uni project website can now play a music file from a url but what I need it to do now is to get the url address
from the mysql database. The url references the mp3 file's location on the server.
I am not sure where to insert the PHP within the media player plugin code (or whether it is possible at all).
Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('player');"><img src="play.png" width="22" height="22"/></a>
<div id="player" style='display:none;>

<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "ooze", "phu7eStu");
mysql_select_db ("ooze");
$query = ("select * from music where music_ID=1");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()." ".$query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" flashvars="audiourl='$row[content]'" width="400" height="27" quality="best"></embed>';
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your query `select content from music, where music_ID = 1` ok ? because syntax must be `select content from music where music_ID = 1`. For php code, it's better to insert it on the top of file, and you store yours parameters ( flashvars, etc....) in variable.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of syntax errors in your code. You should take a look at debugging. This should work however:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
mysql_select_db("...");
$query = "select content from music where music_ID = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error() . " " . $query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" flashvars="audiourl=' . $row['content'] . '" width="400" height="27" quality="best"></embed>';
}
```

Comment: thanks alot I should've tried echoing the whole plugin. Now the media player appears but it doesn't play and I see                          '; } mysql_close($conn); ?> being written out next to it.

Comment: @ozzysmith That's not in my code, you must've missed a quote somewhere.

Comment: The PHP code is wrapped around by this                             <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('player');"><img src="play.png" width="22" height="22" /></a>
<div id="player" style='display:none;>                                                                                                                   </div>                                                              It is basically an image when clicked the player shows and hides. Do you think this might be the problem?

Comment: @ozzysmith no, I think not. Please update your question with the current code.

Comment: Hi I have edited the code and it is now working, the mp3 player appears and when I check the source code the url adress from the database is shown. But the player does not play the file. Do you think this is because the plugin does not work when its echoed out by PHP?

Comment: @ozzysmith no, there is no php magic that will make it not play a file. Is the URL valid? And again, please update your question with the current code.